# is there any way to connect 2 dockers using docker-compose file without docker-swarm-mode

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want  to run a webapp and a db using  Docker, is there any way to connect 2 dockers(webApp Docker Container in One Machine and DB Docker container in another Machine) using docker-compose file without docker-swarm-mode 
I mean 2 separate server 
This is my Mongodb docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
```

Here is my demowebapp docker-compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
  demowebapp:
    image: demoapp:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/app/uploads
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
      - ROOT_URL=http://localhost
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://35.168.21.133/demodb
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Can any one suggest me How to do

Answer (score 0):

Using only one `docker-compose.yml` with compose `version: 2` there is no way to deploy 2 services on two different machines. That's what `version: 3` using a `stack.yml` and swarm-mode are used for.

You can however deploy to two different machines using two `docker-compose.yml` version 2, but will have to connect them using different hostnames/ips than the service-name from the compose-file.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment, i have 2 machines in Each Machine i written one Docker-compose.yml file ,  in webapp Machine  docker-compose.yml, i  have given ip address (52.34.122.58) of another machine the Machine having Mongodb. but i got ""connection  Time out " issue    it can't able to connect  to mongodb of another machine

Comment: Could you run the service in host-mode by adding `network: host` to the service and try again ? (quick check `nc -zv 52.34.122.58 3000`)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to change anything in the sample files you show: you have to connect to the other host's IP address (or DNS name) and the published `ports:`.

Once you're on a different machine (or in a different VM) none of the details around Docker are visible any more.  From the point of view of the system running the Web application, the first system is running MongoDB on port 27017; it might be running on bare metal, or in a container, or port-forwarded from a VM, or using something like HAProxy to pass through from another system; there's literally no way to tell.

The configuration you have to connect to the first server's IP address will work.  I'd set up a DNS system if you don't already have one (BIND, AWS Route 53, ...) to avoid needing to hard-code the IP address.  You also might look at a service-discovery system (I have had good luck with Hashicorp's Consul in the past) which can send you to "the host system running MongoDB" without needing to know which one that is.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, actually i am using aws Ec2 Instance to run the web app and mongodb, when it s come to webapp server docker-compose i given ip and of mongodb but i cant able to connect  to mongodb

Comment: this is error:   MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [54.165.173.255:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out